# GC on unregistered thread in a Core MIDI callback

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am just getting started again with Mac development.

I am using CoreMIDI which is a C API which allows me to define a C callback function to be called from the MIDI server on a separate thread whenever a MIDI message arrives. The registration of this callback is done in Objective-C/C code triggered by an awakeFromNib call.

It seems to work fine, except when I get my first callback I get the following warning message on the console:

```
MidiList(6685,0x103ddb000) malloc: *** auto malloc[6685]: error: GC operation on unregistered thread. Thread registered implicitly. Break on auto_zone_thread_registration_error() to debug.
```

I read up on this online and it sounds like a harmless error. But the weird thing to me is I don't understand how a "GC operation" occurred? My project does have GC enabled, but I thought that was only for the Cocoa parts. And my callback doesn't use any Cocoa code, it is just a free function which uses some CoreMIDI and CoreFoundation functionality (including CFSTR if that matters). Why would a GC operation occur on that thread if i'm not using any Cocoa objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the garbage collector doesn't know you're not using Cocoa on this thread.

The garbage collector that Cocoa sports is a conservative garbage collector: it actually knows next to nothing about how your program is structured. All it does is scanning the stack of each thread, and objects on the heap, for bit patterns that *look like* pointers, and if there's an object at this would-be location, it keeps it alive.

There is, obviously, a possibility for false positives. You can have an integer that has a value looking like a pointer and the garbage collector will believe it's one.

Besides, you may allocate garbage-collected memory in a `malloc`-like way with [`NSAllocateCollectable`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSAllocateCollectable). The GC must take them into account too, especially since the returned pointer could be passed into C code that's not even aware of garbage collection.

**EDIT** Aside from `NSAllocateCollectable`, Core Foundation objects (`CF`-prefixed types) can be made garbage-collected with the help of [`CFMakeCollectable`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTypeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFMakeCollectable). Once it's used, the garbage collector will take care of them.

Comment: OK, thanks! So I should keep doing my CF coding with CFRelease() etc and leave my Cocoa code GC'd as I have been doing?

Comment: @evilfred You can register Core Foundation objects for garbage collection with `CFMakeCollectable` (I'll put the link to documentation in my answer), but if you don't do it, you must continue with `CFRetain`/`CFRelease`, and leave your Cocoa code to garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating pthread, add this `objc_registerThreadWithCollector();` to your pthread.

In case you cannot find a symbol or linking error, use following code,

```
 #include <dlfcn.h>
    void (*registerThreadWithCollector_fn)(void);
    registerThreadWithCollector_fn = (void(*)(void)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "objc_registerThreadWithCollector");
    if (registerThreadWithCollector_fn) {
        (*registerThreadWithCollector_fn)();
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
```